# Redirect page to other page used ip .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I want to do a redirection of the page(post) **(domain.com/general/test/)** to **(domain.com/general/test/2)** with **.htacces**

and used **ip** that is to
 to say i only want to do the redirection for ip xx.xx.xx people.

- I use wordpress cms
- i use permalink domain.com/category/postname

**mycode but not working :( **

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$    
RewriteRule ^test\ /test/2 [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: get red of # in third line

Comment: yes but not working after editing

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/general/test/2   
RewriteRule ^general/test/ /general/test/2 [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: @zikoo test it without IP and see if the rules are ok then make sure your write th IP correct

Comment: @zikoo paste your htaccess file

Comment: @zikoo there is something very important , your URI including general so it must be there , test my rules again if it is ok , if not , put then up after the first four lines in your rules .

Answer (score 0):

@mohammed

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On  
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/2   
RewriteRule ^test/ /test/2 [R,NC,L]
```